# How to make structs for this JSON with Decodable protocol?

Tags: json, swift

I've got this JSON:

```
{
    "$type": "DTOMapper.DTOResponseList`1[[Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto]], DTOMapper",
    "ResponseList": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto]], mscorlib",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$type": "Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto",
                "Title": "NO TE JUNTES CON LUQUITAS",
                "Text": "Porque si tenes un amigo lucas y otro amigo lucas, tenés dos lucas. Pero no te sirven para pagar nada",
                "GroupName": "TGC.Tips1",
                "ConfigurationPath": "TelemedGlobalConfig>Tips>Tips[0]"
            },
            {
                "$type": "Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto",
                "Title": "no te emborraches en las fiestas",
                "Text": "Terminarás pateando globos",
                "GroupName": "TGC.Tips2",
                "ConfigurationPath": "TelemedGlobalConfig>Tips>Tips[1]"
            }
        ]
    },
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ErrorId": 0
}
```

And I'm trying to get access to `Title` and `Text` from the array `$values`.

Here are my current structs but `Root` gives me errors.

```
struct Root : Decodable {  // <<< Type 'Root' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case responseList = "ResponseList" }
    let responseList : ResponseList // <<< Use of undeclared type 'ResponseList'
}

struct Values : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case title = "Title"
        case text = "Text"
    }

    let title : String
    let text : String
}
```

What is the correct way to make this? Also, do I have to make a `struct` and `let` for everything? Even for things I won't use, like `$type`, `GroupName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to make this?

```
do { 
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data) 
}
catch { 
    print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let type: String
    let responseList: ResponseList
    let statusCode, errorID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "$type"
        case responseList = "ResponseList"
        case statusCode = "StatusCode"
        case errorID = "ErrorId"
    }
}

// MARK: - ResponseList
struct ResponseList: Codable {
    let type: String
    let values: [Value]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "$type"
        case values = "$values"
    }
}

// MARK: - Value
struct Value: Codable {
    let title, text:String // left only <<<  access to Title and Text
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "Title"
        case text = "Text"

    }
}
```

> Do I have to make a struct and let for everything? Even for things I won't use, like $type, GroupName?

No only properties that you'll use

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```swift
struct YourStructName: Codable {
    var statusCode: Int
    var errorId: Int
    var type: String // Maybe make this an enum case
    var response: Response

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statusCode = "StatusCode"
        case errorId = "ErrorId"
        case type = "$type"
        case response = "ResponseList"
    }

    struct Response: Codable {
        var type: String // Again, consider making this an enum case
        var values: [ResponseValue]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type = "$type"
            case values = "$values"
        }

        struct ResponseValue: Codable { 
            var title: String
            var text: String 

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { 
                case title = "Title"
                case text = "Text" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```